# Ghost modes in Lattice-Boltzmann Method (LBM)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gas, ghosts

I've read a lot of documents on Lattice-Boltzmann Method (LBM) and "ghost modes" are commonly referred to. It is explained that they are unphysical modes that can pollute the numerical simulation. Multiple techniques can be used to filter them out.

However, I've not found references that explain clearly what they are and what they come from. Can someone give me a clear explanation or a reference that would ?

Answer (score 1):

You can think on them as an "auxiliar" point which will be used to calculate the desired boundary condition (BC) for example. If you want to apply a Dirichlet BC on the hydrodynamic populations $f_i$, is very commom to have points outside the domain, which can be thought as a ghost mode or a boundary point, which will be used to calculate a distance and the desired BC afterwards.

Comment: I think you are talking about ghost methods for immersed boundary.